# ...was a pleasure speaking to you or to speak to you?

Tags: grammar

Is both correct? **It was a pleasure meeting you** and **to meet you**? Or: It was a pleasure **to speak to you/ speaking to you**?

Comment: “to meet you” is more grammatical and natural in my opinion; “meeting” is what Fowler would call a sturdy indefensible: grammar snobs may object, but it will not go away.

Comment: Wanting different words to mean different things, I would use "pleasure to meet you" for a handshake and "pleasure meeting you" for a first conversation. The gerund choice hints ever-so-gently at the progressive whose form it shares. In the same vein, "It was a pleasure to speak *to* you," but "It was a pleasure speaking *with* you." (But this may just be my ear talking.)

Answer (score 1):

"meeting you/to meet you" can be used interchangeably, but in polite usage, you would want to avoid "speaking to you" in favor of "speaking with you". "Speaking to you" implies a power imbalance, that the conversation was one-sided.

Answer (score 0):

They are basically the same.

> It was a pleasure **to speak** to you. speak = infinitive
>
> It was a pleasure **speaking** to you? speaking =  gerund

However, they can be used interchangeably, I believe..